# How can I get the file path from a UIImage?

Tags: ios, objective-c, path, uiimage

Usually it's the other way around, you use the path to display the image. I was wondering if you can get the path if you already have the image.

Comment: You are trying to get the path of UIImage that store in your application??

Comment: Keep in mind that not all `UIImage` instances come from a file. Some are created in code in memory.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

if you already have the image i.e. have added the file to your resources, you can use this to get the file path;

```
NSString *string = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"IMAGE_FILE_NAME" ofType:@"jpg"]; // or ofType:@"png", etc.
```

Answer (score 13):

I don't believe it is possible to get it directly from UIImage.

Best way is to save the image in a directory, then you will have the file path.

```
//image is your UIImage;

if (image != nil)
{
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,
                                                         NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString* path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:
                      @"test.png" ];
    NSData* data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
    [data writeToFile:path atomically:YES];
}
```

`path` will be your filepath.

Answer (score 8):

Once a UIImage is created, the image data is loaded into memory and no longer connected to the file on disk. As such, the file can be deleted or modified without consequence to the UIImage and there is no way of getting the source path from a UIImage.

Comment: Yet the [official documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html) refers to "[w]hen you attempt to draw an image whose data has been purged, the image object automatically reloads the data from its original file." ("Images and Memory Management"). There may be a private API that allows to access the file (or `nil` if there is no file backing up the object data). Any clue?

Comment: You are correct that internally the object must have some sort of reference to the source path. A bit of further digging shows it likely is contained somehow within the `CGDataProviderRef` on the `CGImage`.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. It looks so, although `CGDataProvider.h` does not yield much information.

A weak but practical answer to the original question seems to be "we can't access the file path for a `UIImage` object", unfortunately. Time will come.

Comment: CGDataProvider is essentially an abstract superclass. There are several concrete subclasses, and someone willing to invest considerable time could use `CGDataProviderGetTypeID` to determine which subclass it is and what the structure looks like. The practical answer is my original answer: There is no way of getting the source path from a UIImage.